# org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.TestSuiteExecutionException: Could not complete execution for Gradle Test Executor 5

Tags: java, gradle, junit4

Java 8,

I want to use JUnit 4 in my java project.

In my build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm:1.5.2'

   testImplementation('org.assertj:assertj-core:3.21.0')
   testImplementation('org.mockito:mockito-core:4.0.0')

   testImplementation('junit:junit:4.13.2')

}
```

Here my unit test:

```
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.*;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

public class VsatVlansNSTest {


    @BeforeClass
    public static void setupAll() {
     //
    }

    @Test
    public void find_NS_2_4_higher_matcher() {
     // some test here
    }
}
```

But I get error:

```
g.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.TestSuiteExecutionException: Could not complete execution for Gradle Test Executor 5.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:63)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:133)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.junit.platform.commons.PreconditionViolationException: Cannot create Launcher without at least one TestEngine; consider adding an engine implementation JAR to the classpath
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.Preconditions.condition(Preconditions.java:296)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.<init>(DefaultLauncher.java:48)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory.create(LauncherFactory.java:105)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory.create(LauncherFactory.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: Are you facing this error when you run `gradlew test`? I am running this code with the same dependencies with Java 15, and am not facing any errors.

Comment: @JustInCoding I try with "gradle test" but get the same error

Answer (score 19):

Most probably, you've not added a dependency named junit engine, add those like this:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.1'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.1'
}
```

Comment: I get error: Could not find org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:4.13.2.

Comment: Edited the answer, but it uses JUnit 5

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep using JUnit 4 (like mentioned in the question), check your Gradle build file for any `useJUnitPlatform()` and remove it.

Instead your test block should look like this:

```
 test {
     useJUnit()  // JUnit 4
     
     // ... other config ...
 }
```

With this you still can use JUnit 4 in legacy projects via Gradle without the need of upgrading to JUnit 5.